# What is the correct way to ONLY handle a promise error?

Tags: javascript, promise

See the example below, where **method** will return a promise and resolve/reject that promise accordingly. I'm not interested in handling it's resolve at this point, I just want to handle the reject.

Is there a better, cross browser way of doing it without declaring that useless success function?

```
  MyClass.method().then((sData) => {
    // Nothing to do here
  }, (eData) => {
    // Important code to run here
  })
```

In my code I'm using AngularJS promises. However the question is relevant for other common libraries and the native Promise object.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch

Comment: i think it's ok. i have seen this behaviour before.

Comment: You mean like [`.catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)?

Comment: i thought he was talking about the `resolve` and `reject` but yuh it is not very clear

Comment: @DrNio yeah, i'm not sure what's not clear there, i've changed the question a little, see if it makes more sense now.

Comment: @ChrisG Yes. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: `Is there a better, cross browser way of doing it`  If you don't mind trans-piling for older browsers, there is `async / await`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the other answers state use the `.catch` function for this.

```
MyClass.method()
  .catch(error => { error handling logic (async)})
```

What I would like to add is the following:

Normally in the `.then()` function you provide 2 callbacks like this (these callbacks always will be executed asynchronous):

```
const promise2 = doSomething().then(successCallback, failureCallback);
```

However `.catch()` is shorthand for `then()` where the successCallback is filled in with `null`.

```
then(null, failureCallback)
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes! You can use [`catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) function for this:

```
MyClass.method()
  .catch(error => { ... })
```

Assuming `MyClass.method()` returns a valid Promise API object, `catch` should be able to catch any rejection.

Comment: Comparing .catch with my code in the question, it seems like catch would also capture unhandled exceptions while the reject function doesn't?

Comment: @caiocpricci2 -- so you don't want that?

Comment: @caiocpricci2, that's how Promises work. A Promise is rejected when `reject` is called or an error is thrown. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Syntax)

Answer (score 3):

> YourClass.method()   .catch(error => { ... })

See for Reference :
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABhBo.png)

[image: Promise]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Promise's `.catch` method.

```
MyClass.method().catch(error => {
  // handle the error here
});
```